# local variable '' referenced before assignment - using modelforms in view

Tags: django

I'm trying to using the form in my views, but checking either if the user is logged on or not to change some fields depending on it.

here are my **views.py**

```
def PostAd(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        obj = Account.objects.get(user=request.user)
        if request.method == "POST":
            ad_post_form = AdPostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if ad_post_form.is_valid():
                ad_post_form.created_by = request.user
                if obj.role == 'admin':
                    ad_post_form.is_active = True
                ad_post_form.save()
                return redirect('home')
        else:
            ad_post_form = AdPostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    else:
        if request.method == "POST":
            ad_post_form = AdPostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if ad_post_form.is_valid():
                ad_post_form.created_by = 'guest'
                otp_number = random.randint(100000, 999999)
                ad_post_form.otp = otp_number
                ad_post_form.save()
                return redirect('home')

            else:
                ad_post_form = AdPostForm()


    context = {
        'ad_post_form': ad_post_form,
    }

    return render(request, 'pages/post-ad.html', context)
```

for some reason. the variable `ad_post_form` goes out of scope in a specific step that I can't find out. so it gives me the error `local variable 'ad_post_form' referenced before assignment.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If user is not authenticated and request method is not POST `ad_post_form` will not be defined. You can just define `ad_post_form` at the top of view to fix:

```
def PostAd(request):
    ad_post_form = AdPostForm()
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
    ...
```